# What is the best way to sort a doubly linked list of objects using compareTo

Tags: java, sorting

I have a doubly linked list of objects, and have a comparable interface in order to compare these objects. I'm just wondering, is there a standard/ best sort algorithm used to sort the list in this case?

thanks for any help!

Comment: To clarify: this is a custom data structure, right? (You're not just using `LinkedList`).

Comment: Yeah this is a custom data structure, thanks @immibis

Answer (score 1):

You have a `LinkedList<T extends Comparable>` instance then the best way is to use the facility function `Collections.sort`.

If you have your custom data structure then you could make it implement the [`List<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface to be able to use the `Collections` methods (which includes `sort` and many others).